# How to retrieve a value from another table using subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
abserve_hotels                  

hotel_id    name             

1           A                      
2           B                      
3           C                      
4           D                      
4           E                      
6           G                      
7           F       

wishlists   

id       user_id     hotel_id   

1          5            1   
2          5            2    
3          7            1  
4          1            7
5          1            5
```

I have these two tables,from which I need to check which hotels are added to wishlist by the current user.If the current `user_id` is `1`,hen I have to send the wishlist `hotel_id's` as a column name `wishlist` in `hotels` table using query.

I tried like this

```
SELECT `h`.*,(SELECT `w`.`hotel_id` FROM `wishlists` AS `w` JOIN `abserve_hotels` AS `ah` ON `w`.`hotel_id` = `ah`.`hotel_id` AND `w`.`user_id` = 1 GROUP BY `w`.`hotel_id`)as `wish` FROM `abserve_hotels` AS `h` WHERE 1 AND `city` = "madurai" AND `country` = "india"
```

But it show me an error like `subquery return more than one value`

How should I do this,Someone help me..

Answer (score 0):

you can directly achieve this by using JOIN

SELECT h.* from abserve_hotels  LEFT JOIN wishlists w on h.id=w.hotel_id WHERE w.user_id=1 GROUP by w.hotel_id